# Proving the limit of a sequence of functions must be polynomial.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing, uniform-convergence

Let $n \geq 1$ and let $\left(f_n (z)\right)_n$ be a sequence of polynomials whose coefficients are in $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose that $(f_n (z))_n$ converges uniformly to a function $f(z)$ on $\mathbb{C}$. Show that $f(z)$ is a polynomial.

I know that "$(f_n (z))_n$ converges uniformly to $f(z)$ on $\mathbb{C}$" is equivalent to 
$$\sup_{z\in \mathbb{C}}|f_n(z)-f(z)| \to 0 \, \, \text{as} \,\, n\to \infty$$
which I think is equivalent to 
$$ \forall \epsilon >0\,\,\, \exists N\,\, \text{s.t.}\,\, \forall z \in \mathbb{C} \,\,\,|f_n(z) - f(z)|<\epsilon \,\,\text{when} \,\, n>N \,.$$

Unfortunately I don't know where to go from here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A bounded entire  function is constant.

Comment: @James That series does not converge uniformly, at last not on $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @ncmathsadist Is there another method to solve this? We haven't actually covered that theorem in lectures so I don't think this solution would be accepted.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Same question to you, sir.

Comment: @MathWolf You may have already seen the notion of entire functions (Page 6). Use Liouville’s Theorem (page 90), and then you have the proof. Remember that _depending on when_ in the week lectures are and _whether your lecturer wasted a lecture on recap_, you may be further behind in your lectures than you should be

Comment: @Dino I just checked and we are nowhere near that theorem yet so I'm pretty sure that a solution with it would be accepted as the theorem itself hasn't been covered yet. But thank you for the hint.

Comment: I think it would be good to tell us what results you know. For example, do you know Casorati-Weierstrass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stronger result holds, and it doesn't have that much to do with complex analysis: Let $E\subset \mathbb C$ be unbounded. If $p_n$ is a sequence of polynomials with $p_n\to f$ uniformly on $E,$ then $f$ is a polynomial. (There can be at most one such polynomial, since $E$ is infinite.)

Proof: First, note that if a polynomial $p$ is bounded on $E,$ then $p$ is a constant. That's because if $\deg p>0,$ then it is elementary that as $|z|\to \infty$ within $E,$ $|p(z)|\to \infty.$ Thus we must have $\deg p=0,$ which implies $p$ is constant.

We are given $p_n\to f$ uniformly on $E.$ This implies there exists $N$ such that $n\ge N$ implies $|p_n-p_N|<1$ on $E.$ By the above, $p_n-p_N$ is a constant $c_n$ for $n\ge N.$ Evaluate at any $z\in E$ and let $n\to \infty$ to see that $c_n$ converges to some $c.$ So letting $n\to \infty$ in the equation $p_n=c_n +p_N$ gives $f= c+P_N.$ Thus $f$ is a polynomial as desired.

Comment: Brilliant solution! Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome, certainly.

Answer (score 0):

Find $N$ such that $|f_N(z)-f(z)|<1$ for al $z$. 
Then the function $f_N-f$ is entire(!) and bounded, hence a constant $c$, and therefore $f=f_N+c$.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not familiar with the term "entire(!)". Also, I don't understand why $f_N - f$ being bounded implies that $f_N - f$ is constant. Is there another method for proving $f(z)$ is a polynomial that I might be more familiar with? Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Entire means differentiable everywhere.  Lioville's theorem says that a bounded entire function is constatn.